# the disk drive for /media/sdc1 is not ready or not presented - in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

When I tried boot PC - I saw next message:

```
the disk drive for /media/sdc1 is not ready or not presented
Continue to wait or Press S to skip mounting or M for manual recovery
```

I used `S` and now want to know how to solve this issue.
Here is my `fdisk` information:

```
nazar_art@nazar-desctop:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 160.0 GB, 160041885696 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 19457 cylinders, total 312581808 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x000e28b8

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048   310484991   155241472   83  Linux
/dev/sda2       310487038   312580095     1046529    5  Extended
/dev/sda5       310487040   312580095     1046528   82  Linux swap / Solaris

Disk /dev/sdb: 4009 MB, 4009754624 bytes
16 heads, 32 sectors/track, 15296 cylinders, total 7831552 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xd8e1f237

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          32     7831551     3915760    b  W95 FAT32

Disk /dev/sdc: 993 MB, 993001472 bytes
2 heads, 1 sectors/track, 969728 cylinders, total 1939456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1             133     1939455      969661+   6  FAT16
```

And below `blkid` info:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="5f5d330f-d5f2-4157-9496-94f1dce2f181" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="84747ef4-6f50-49bc-9df1-fcba364ba299" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="8BAA-7FA6" TYPE="vfat"
```

And the `/etc/fstab` file info:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc                                       /proc           proc  nodev,noexec,nosuid       0  0  
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=5f5d330f-d5f2-4157-9496-94f1dce2f181  /               ext4  errors=remount-ro         0  1  
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=84747ef4-6f50-49bc-9df1-fcba364ba299  none            swap  sw                        0  0  
/dev/fd0                                   /media/floppy0  auto  rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8  0  0  
/dev/sdc1                                  /media/sdc1     vfat  noexec                    0  0  
/dev/sdb1                                  /media/sdb1     vfat  defaults                  0  0  
/dev/sdd1                                  /media/sdd1     vfat  uid=nazar_art             0  0
```

**Update:**

now this is output after `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` running:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 993 MB, 993001472 bytes
2 heads, 1 sectors/track, 969728 cylinders, total 1939456 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1             133     1939455      969661+   6  FAT16
```

***Edit:***

`sudo ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/` has next result:

```
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 21 23:48 5f5d330f-d5f2-4157-9496-94f1dce2f181 -> ../../sda1
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 21 23:48 84747ef4-6f50-49bc-9df1-fcba364ba299 -> ../../sda5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Aug 21 23:48 8BAA-7FA6 -> ../../sdb1
```

And unfortunately any `sdc` here?

***- Why exactly this happen?

 - And how to solve this trouble?***

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdc` that is the disk that is apparently missing.

Comment: @terdon I updated question.

Comment: Is sdc an external drive?

Comment: @terdon yes it is. Do I need update to `/etc/fstab` for mounting FAT16 and FAT32?

Comment: @terdon I tried to add `/dev/sdc1 /media/sdc1 vfat shortname=mixed,codepage=850,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=100,noauto,user 0 0` to `/etc/fstab`. But after `sudo mount -a` have - `mount: block device /dev/sdc1 is write-protected, mounting read-only`

Comment: In the future, please include such details in your question. The fact that this is an external drive is the cause of the problem.

Comment: @terdon I found this only after asked question.

Comment: No worries, that was not a reprimand, just a recommendation to make future questions clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem here is that since this is an external drive, at the time the system tries to mount it it has not yet been assigned a `/dev/sdX` name. You should be able to fix this by changing your `fstab` to use [`UUID`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier) instead.

First, get the UUID of your drive. Run this command when the drive is connected:

```
sudo blkid | grep sdc
```

That should return a line that looks something like this:

```
/dev/sdb1: LABEL="MY_DISK" UUID="ABCDEF123456" TYPE="ntfs"
```

`ABCDEF123456` is the UUID of your drive. Now, edit your `fstab` accordingly (replacing `ABCDEF123456` with your real UUID of course):

```
UUID=ABCDEF123456  /media/sdc1  vfat  noexec   0  0
```

For more information on persistent naming, have a look at [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Persistent_block_device_naming) page from the Arch Linux wiki.

Comment: but one moment this line doesn't have any output `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdc`. I solved this with a little bit another way by `/dev/sdc1 /media/sdc1 vfat shortname=mixed,codepage=850,umask=002,uid=1000,gid=100,noauto,user 0 0` and `sudo mount -a` after this

Comment: @nazar_art `mount -a` should have worked anyway. Read through the arch wiki page I linked to for other ways of getting a persistent name for your drive. What you did is not a solution, you just set the drive to not be mounted automatically. If that is what you want you should also have a look at `autofs`.

Comment: Why it isn't right solution, I can't understand. After all this steps I also add option to samba `sudo gedit /etc/samba/smb.conf` into [global] section `usershare owner only = false`. And I didn't have any output after `ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid/ | grep sdc` for sdc or sdc1...

Comment: @nazar_art samba? What does samba have to do with it? And it is not a solution because if you add `noauto` to `fstab`, you will need to manually mount the drive every time you need it. If that is OK for you, then great but that was not your original question. I have edited my answer and added a way of finding the UUID of USB drives (sorry for the mistake), it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this topic while trying to figure out how to skip `fsck` at boot on my external drives that are genuinely not present at boot most of the time. The solution for me was to add `nobootwait` to the mount options field (fourth column) in `/etc/fstab`.